# How to listen for document events that user triggers while palette window is open

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting

Is there a way to listen for document events that the user triggers while a palette window is open?
I have looked at the documentation for something like `document.addEventLister` or something, but I have not found anything.
For example, I want to listen for the Paint Brush Tool and update my open palette window ui based on that.
Here is what I have tried:

```
var isDone, s2t, waitForRedraw, win, windowResource;
var count = 0;
var document;
// Shortcut function
s2t = function(stringID) {
  return app.stringIDToTypeID(stringID);
};

waitForRedraw = function() {
  var d;
  d = new ActionDescriptor();
  d.putEnumerated(s2t('state'), s2t('state'), s2t('redrawComplete'));
  return executeAction(s2t('wait'), d, DialogModes.NO);
};

//sentinel variable
isDone = false;

windowResource = "palette {  \    orientation: 'column', \    alignChildren: ['fill', 'top'],  \    preferredSize:[130, 130], \    text: 'Brush Stroke Counter 1.0',  \    margins:15, \    \    sliderPanel: Panel { \        orientation: 'row', \        alignChildren: 'right', \        margins:15, \        text: ' Brush Stroke Count ', \        st: StaticText { text: '0', characters: 5, justify: 'left'} \        } \    \    bottomGroup: Group{ \        cd: Checkbox { text:'Count Enabled', value: true }, \        cancelButton: Button { text: 'Close', properties:{name:'cancel'}, size: [120,24], alignment:['right', 'center'] }, \    }\}";

win = new Window(windowResource);

// Button listeners
win.bottomGroup.cancelButton.onClick = function() {
  return isDone = true;
};

win.onClose = function() {
  return isDone = true;
};

win.show();


activeDocument.addEventListener("Pnt ", function(){
     alert("I'm painting!");
});

while (isDone === false) {

     //listen for user painting here?
  alert(app.currentTool);

  app.refresh(); // or, alternatively, waitForRedraw();

}
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

No, if you want this data then its time to wirte a plugin in C++.